# Use increment instead of random string in AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

When I upload files with similar filenames Amazon S3 adds random chars to the filename. How I can change it to use increment instead?

Comment: Can you show an example? I've always thought that S3 would override the older object with the same name...

Comment: Is versioning enabled for your s3 objects?

Comment: I didn't think S3 would ever change filenames. Can you show us exactly what you're doing, web interface screenshots or API calls?

Comment: for example, I uploaded 120x160.jpg. When I upload the same file s3 changes the second filename to 120x160_ATasbd,jpg. But I need 120x160_2.jpg

Comment: Impulsively, I'd suggest coding around it: read the bucket listing, and detect/handle collisions yourself?